# css file is showing render blocking in google page speed

Tags: css, html

My website (https://www.gkduniya.com) score in google page inside in 94/100. But still shows CSS file as render blocking.

My css file is connected as:

```
link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen.
```

Suggestion needed to proper link so that render blocking tag can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the CSS, but one of the major culprits is importing a css

- Eliminate any @import in your style.css, by linking the imported CSS(s) directly or copying them into the style.css. This is mostly located at the top of the css and it looks like this:
   @import url("style.css")